# I am trying to make a 3D animated text in blender but I cannot find the Faces option

Tags: interface, edit-mode, text-object

Normally projects get this option
[image: this is an image i got from the tutorial im following on youtube]

but on my local machine I just cant find this option. This is my POV
[image: my pov]

so could someone please help me with this!
blender version: 3.0.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A text is not a mesh, if you want to convert it to mesh, switch back to *Object* mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and right click > *Convert To > Mesh*.

Comment: man, do you ever sleep? :) looks like you're answering questions 24/7/365 :))

Comment: @JachymMichal: This is an AI bot from 2030. Pretty old technology because he lags often. And furthermore it still a bit buggy because sometimes it answers questions in comments (so it still can't differentiate between comments and answers) and it has this kind of awareness that it asks questions although it knows the answer...So yeah - from your perspective from 2022 pretty amazing - from us just old technology. :D

Comment: we are a whole team actually, we are growing and hiring btw!!!!

Comment: @chris that actually explains *a lot* :))

Comment: @moonboots: do you hire only bots? or human beings too? what about cyborgs? and what would you pay for robots from 2055 working for u? (if you have one, you can fire all your employees of course....) so i am not sure whether i can reconcile that with my conscience?!

Comment: what are human beings?